# Where to change the contact us page in Joomla

Tags: joomla-2.5, basics, contact-form

I am new to Joomla.
Please visit this link : http://naadiastrology.info/index.php/contact-us

How to edit the contact-us page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Joomla backend, go to:

**Components** (top menu) >> **Contacts** >> **Contacts**

Here you can add and edit contacts. There will already be a contact pre-added so you can simply open it and edit it to your liking.

Comment: I've checked it already. In your backend, navigate to `www.example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_contact`, where example.com is your domain. This is the page where you edit the contact details. The form for this is generated by Joomla. I think the **Links** are being pulled from **Components** >> **Weblinks**

Comment: hi, thanks a lot,  but it's displying in components > Contact Manager> Contact  and in right side option : "contact form" is there. it's displaying there. but under other information , it's displaying some other "text2" . I wanted those text to appear on frontend. how to do it. let me know if you need any clarifications. 

to copy paste , "text2" is lot of words.

Comment: Hey, this is what you should see (https://www.ostraining.com/cdn/images/stories/tutuploadsUntitled.png)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks a lot . 

I got the solution.

But is there any option to display the text which is present under "components" > "contact" > "contact" > "Contact Manager">  "Contact "> "other details "text.

I wanted to display the text which is under "other details" on contact us page.

how to do It. please help me.

Comment: To display it, open the **Display Options** tab on the right hand side and set **Misc Information** to **Show**

Comment: please visit his link : http://naadiastrology.info/

on bottom you can see : "bottom menu" . below 6 links are there, below that some empty space is there.

how to add some text in those empty space. please help me.